# List most frequently selected items(3 items) at top of the adapter using android list fragments?

Tags: android, listview, android-listfragment

I've used list fragment and list view for displaying manufacture items. For that I've created a manufacture adapter for list out the items and it list more than hundred items. Now My requirement is to show the mostly frequently selected items( three items more enough) at the top of list.

```
 getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ManufacturerListAdapter adapter = (ManufacturerListAdapter) getListAdapter();
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);

            String manufacturerId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ManufacturersColumns.MANUFACTURER_ID));
            int    isUserCreated  = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("usergen"));

            EditableItemActivity activity = (EditableItemActivity) getActivity();
            if (activity != null) activity.setManufacturer(manufacturerId, isUserCreated > 0);
            hideKeyboard();
        }

    });
```

I added a snippet of on click event of listed items. Hope it will more helpful to understand my requirement.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

`ManufacturerListAdapter` will need to return those "mostly frequently selected items" for the first few row positions (e.g., `0`, `1`, and `2`), with the others in whatever order you wish.

Since `ManufacturerListAdapter` would appear to be a subclass of `CursorAdapter`, one approach is:

- Do one query to get your "mostly frequently selected items" into one `Cursor`
- Do another query to get the rest, in the desired order, into another `Cursor`
- Stitch the two `Cursor` objects together using [a `MergeCursor`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MergeCursor.html)
- Use the `MergeCursor` with your `ManufacturerListAdapter`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. could you please share some snippet code to do this?