# Calculating frequency of selected column values in SQLite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

**db structure:**

```
public final class ManufacturersColumns implements MyStyleBaseColumns {
public static final String ALIAS           = "alias";
public static final String MANUFACTURER_ID = "manufacturer_id";
public static final String NAME            = "name";

public static final String TABLE_NAME = "manufacturers";

public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                + _ID             + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + ALIAS           + " TEXT, "
                + DATE_DELETED    + " DATE, "
                + DATE_CREATED    + " DATE, "
                + DATE_MODIFIED   + " DATE, "
                + MANUFACTURER_ID + " TEXT, "
                + NAME            + " TEXT "
        + ");";}






public final class ManufacturersUserCreatedColumns implements MyStyleBaseColumns {
    public static final String MANUFACTURER_ID = "manufacturer_id";
    public static final String NAME            = "name";

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "manufacturers_user_created";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                    + _ID             + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + MANUFACTURER_ID + " TEXT, "
                    + NAME            + " TEXT, "
                    + DATE_CREATED    + " DATE, "
                    + DATE_MODIFIED   + " DATE, "
                    + DATE_DELETED    + " DATE, "
                    + SYNC_FLAG       + " NUMERIC " 
            + ");";
}
```

Now we're using the below mentioned query for listing the name's:

```
<string name="kGetAllManufacturers"><![CDATA["SELECT _id, manufacturer_id, name, alias, usergen FROM (SELECT _id, manufacturer_id, name, alias, 0 AS usergen FROM manufacturers UNION SELECT _id, manufacturer_id, name, '' AS alias, 1 AS usergen FROM manufacturers_user_created) main ORDER BY lower(name) ASC"]]>
```

Requirement is:

Need to alter above query for listing name's which is frequently selected at top.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "frequently selected"? How would this information be determined?

Comment: I mean, to calculate the count of column values. For example the above manufactures table has column "name". This column contains list of names , from this i want to be show the top three names which is most frequently selected by user's.

Comment: So when you say "selected by users", you actually mean "exists in the database"?

Comment: yes. "manufacturers" table has all manufacture name's it's predefined in database. But "manufacturers_user_created" table for user can created their own manufacture name that will be inserted into database.

Comment: Please edit your question to show several example records and the desired output.

Comment: will you able to share some suggestions regarding this question ?

Comment: Not without understand what you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957097/list-most-frequently-selected-items3-items-at-top-of-the-adapter-using-android/18958147?noredirect=1#18958147     please refer this link, hopefully you will get some more idea's. Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: That other question does not specify what "most frequently selected items" means either. Please edit your question to show some example records and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my issues by using this query.

```
<string name="kGetAllManufacturers"><![CDATA["SELECT _id, man_id, name, alias, usergen, count(man_id) as amount from (SELECT c._id as _id, c.manufacturer_id as man_id, m.name as name, m.alias as alias, 0 AS usergen FROM clothes c INNER JOIN manufacturers m ON m.manufacturer_id = c.manufacturer_id UNION all SELECT c._id as _id, c.manufacturer_id as man_id, ucm.name as name, '' AS alias, 1 AS usergen FROM clothes c INNER JOIN manufacturers_user_created ucm ON ucm.manufacturer_id = c.manufacturer_id UNION SELECT _id, manufacturer_id, name, alias, 0 AS usergen FROM manufacturers UNION SELECT _id, manufacturer_id, name, '' AS alias, 1 AS usergen FROM manufacturers_user_created ) main GROUP BY man_id, name ORDER BY COUNT(man_id) desc"]]></string>
```